# Can ngFor only render once and never again check for changes?

Tags: angular

im working in a menu that loads the items from a tree structured object. currently im using nested ngFor but the menu use some jquery and stuff to make it fancy(animation, fade scrollbar, etc..) and using ngFor have a huge impact on performance. the animation stutter or dont even show. if the same menu is writen in the template by hand (same elements, same levels, same everything) works fine.
Im not sure but i think is becouse the change detector is slowing it down.

The menu does not change after entering the system. So I want some way to render it once when the object is received and leave it without detecting more changes

Comment: @PaulRooney What do u think is the real problem here ? the menu load once on login and never change until relogin.

Comment: Maybe the way the animation manipulates the data and the change detection don't play nicely together. It's hard to be sure without some code to run. Hopefully the answer below will solve your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your menu is a separate component, you could try changing the change detection strategy to `OnPush`, this will make change detection run only when the refference of an `@Input` changes, this may solve your problem. If you have none, it will never run.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-menu',
  templateUrl: 'my-menu.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
```

Comment: This sound nice, im going to try it.